# Once I create a shape with CSS, how can I use its center as a focus point for another CSS shape?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a circle and a square. I want the square's focus to be the focus of the circle. That way when I make the shape larger or smaller it's position is still where I want it. How can this be done?

Basically as a learning tool, the image below is what I want to recreate using only html and css. But for my question, only focus on the outer circle and outer square please.

[image: Circle and sqaure with the same focus point]

Comment: Will both shapes change size? What I mean is will the square and the circle scale?

Comment: The optimal method would be an SVG. Otherwise your heading towards *divitis* just to create something that is better served as an image.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "focus" please

Comment: Thank you both, Alvaro and web-tiki, for your responses! This is my first time on this site for asking my own question and I am astonished at the speed and helpfulness of its users. When I gain enough knowledge I'll give back to the community as well. To state more succinctly, I am recreating the circle and square shapes above and want to be able to cut the code out to place in any work i have. meaning, adjustments to padding or margins to get the affect wont work everywhere. The answers supplied helped answer my question perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Lefty you should choose the most helpfull answer and acept it. More [info here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/245708)

Answer (score 2):

you could do it with a mix of `translate`and `transform-origin`.

basically center your elements in the container with:

```
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

and as the square will not be centered if it's rotate 45 degrees, you change the origin with:

```
  transform-origin: 85% -35%;
```

you have an example in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/mzqs8ukL/1/)** (hover over the elements to check them  shrinking and expanding

Comment: Yeah.. I thought the same after reading your answer. I have no idea now what he is looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use one div with a pseudo element. Both elements will resize together according to the width of the viewport :

```css
.circ{
  position:relative;
  width:30%;
  padding-bottom:30%;
  border:1px solid #333;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.circ:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:7.5%; left:7.5%;
  width:85%; height:85%;
  border:1px solid #333;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circ"></div>
```